# Using boost geometry to find intersection of line segments

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

I am trying to use the boost geometry method `intersects` with my own point class, successfully registered with the boost geometry library.

The boost documentation ( https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection/intersection_3.html ) says that I can use a vector of points as the output parameter.  So I wrote this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using namespace std;

class cxy
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    cxy( double X, double Y )
        : x( X )
        , y( Y )
    {

    }
    /// boost geometry insists on a default constructor
    cxy()
        : cxy(0,0)
    {

    }
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D( cxy, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y )
typedef bg::model::segment<cxy> segment_t;

int main()
{
    cxy a(0,0);
    cxy b(1,1);
    cxy c(1,0);
    cxy d(0,1) ;

    std::vector<cxy> out;

    //////////////// this compiles

    bg::intersection(segment_t{a, b}, segment_t{c, d}, out);

    //////////////// this does not!!!

    segment_t ab( a, b );
    segment_t cd( c, d );
    bg::intersects( ab, cd, out );

    return 0;
}
```

To be clear: my problem was that I was confused between `intersection` and `intersects`

The following code compiles and produces the expected results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using namespace std;

class cxy
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    cxy( double X, double Y )
        : x( X )
        , y( Y )
    {

    }
    /// boost geometry insists on a default constructor
    cxy()
        : cxy(0,0)
    {

    }
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D( cxy, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y )
typedef bg::model::segment<cxy> segment_t;

int main()
{
    cxy a(0,0);
    cxy b(1,1);
    cxy c(1,0);
    cxy d(0,1) ;

    segment_t ab( a, b );
    segment_t cd( c, d );
    std::vector<cxy> out;
    if( ! bg::intersection( ab, cd, out ) ) {
       std::cout << "no intersection\n";
       return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "intersection at " << out[0].x <<" " << out[0].y << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking "whether a [*intersects*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects/intersects_2_two_geometries.html) b".

However, your third argument suggests you wanted instead to ask for "the [*intersection*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection/intersection_3.html)":

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/040579975c911c7d)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/segment.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using namespace std;

struct cxy {
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    cxy(double X, double Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}
    cxy() = default;
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(cxy, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y)
using segment_t = bg::model::segment<cxy>;
using points_t = bg::model::multi_point<cxy>;

int main() {
    cxy a{0, 0}, b{1, 1}, c{1, 0}, d{0, 1};
    std::vector<cxy> out;
    bg::intersection(segment_t{a, b}, segment_t{c, d}, out);

    // for output, use a multipoint model or register your vector as one
    points_t pts;
    bg::intersection(segment_t{a, b}, segment_t{c, d}, pts);
    std::cout << bg::wkt(pts) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
MULTIPOINT((0.5 0.5))
```

---

Comment: How very strange!  It compiles if the segments are constructed in the parameter list, but not if they are constructed before the call.  Can you explain what is going on, please?  ( i have edited my question to show the strangeness )

Comment: Read carefully. I spelled it out. With hyperlinks :)

Comment: Sorry, I was short on time earlier: `intersects` != `intersection`. (Your `out` parameter is accidentally interprested as [a strategy for the `intersects` predicate](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects.html))

Comment: Ooooh!  So simple!.  I missed the answer because distracted by all the other details.   My bad, but a one line would have done it "you should call Intersection not intersects"

Comment: I'm sure when you read my answer know, you will see that I tried very hard to drive the point home. With hyperlinks and italics :) But yeah. I'm guessing the curse of completing IDEs?

Comment: (Also, it took me some minutes to find out, so don't feel bad)

Comment: The return value from intersection is undocumented and weird.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63118550/16582