# What does boost::geometry::intersection return

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

The documentation for `boost::geometry::intersection`( https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection/intersection_3.html ) says the function returns a bool.  However the docs do NOT say what the return value indicates.  I guessed it would return true if an intersection was found.

Wrong!!!

This code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using namespace std;

class cxy
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    cxy( double X, double Y )
        : x( X )
        , y( Y )
    {

    }
    /// boost geometry insists on a default constructor
    cxy()
        : cxy(0,0)
    {

    }
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D( cxy, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y )
typedef bg::model::segment<cxy> segment_t;

int main()
{
    cxy a(1,0);
    cxy b(1,1);
    cxy c(0,0.5);
    cxy d(0.5,0.5) ;

    segment_t ab( a, b );
    segment_t cd( c, d );
    std::vector<cxy> out;
    if( ! bg::intersection( ab, cd, out ) ) {
       std::cout << "intersection returned false\n";
       return 1;
    }
    if( ! out.size() ) {
        std::cout << "no intersection point!\n";
        return 2;
    }
    std::cout << "intersection at " << out[0].x <<" " << out[0].y << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
no intersection point!
```

What is the return of true indicating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is true indicating no errors. E.g. deep down the call chain:

```
template <typename RobustPolicy, typename GeometryOut, typename Strategy>
static inline bool apply(Geometry1 const& geometry1,
        Geometry2 const& geometry2,
        RobustPolicy const& robust_policy,
        GeometryOut& geometry_out,
        Strategy const& strategy)
{
    typedef typename geometry::detail::output_geometry_value
        <
            GeometryOut
        >::type SingleOut;

    intersection_insert
        <
            Geometry1, Geometry2, SingleOut,
            overlay_intersection
        >::apply(geometry1, geometry2, robust_policy,
                 geometry::detail::output_geometry_back_inserter(geometry_out),
                 strategy);

    return true;
}
```

That's at

```
#0  0x000055555555598c in boost::geometry::dispatch::intersection<boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, boost::geometry::segment_tag, boost::geometry::segment_tag, false>::apply<boost::geometry::detail::no_rescale_policy, std::vector<cxy, std::allocator<cxy> >, boost::geometry::strategy::intersection::cartesian_segments<void> > (geometry1=..., geometry2=..., robust_policy=..., geometry_out=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0, strategy=...) at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/intersection/interface.hpp:63
#1  0x0000555555555842 in boost::geometry::resolve_strategy::intersection::apply<boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, std::vector<cxy, std::allocator<cxy> > > (geometry1=..., geometry2=..., geometry_out=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0) at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/intersection/interface.hpp:175
#2  0x00005555555556ed in boost::geometry::resolve_variant::intersection<boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy> >::apply<std::vector<cxy, std::allocator<cxy> >, boost::geometry::default_strategy> (geometry1=..., geometry2=..., geometry_out=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0, strategy=...) at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/intersection/interface.hpp:198
#3  0x00005555555554f3 in boost::geometry::intersection<boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, boost::geometry::model::segment<cxy>, std::vector<cxy, std::allocator<cxy> > > (geometry1=..., geometry2=..., geometry_out=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0) at /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_73_0/boost/geometry/algorithms/detail/intersection/interface.hpp:403
#4  0x0000555555554eab in main () at /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:40
```

I looked at the OGC Simple Feature Specification that [Boost Geoetry follows](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/introduction.html)

> The library follows existing conventions:
>
> - conventions from boost
> - conventions from the std library conventions and
> - names from one of the OGC standards on geometry and, more
>   specificly, from the [OGC Simple Feature Specification](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa)

It conceptually models the algorithm without the return value:

[image]

I checked all the implementations in algorithms/detail/intersection (areal_areal.hpp, box_box.hpp, implementation.hpp, interface.hpp, multi.hpp) and nothing returns false.

### TL;DR Summary

The return-value is specifically *undocumented*, in other words: it's an implementation detail you may not depend on.

In terms of the library interface, documented interface may not change (without warning) in new versions. A lot of things that are 'discoverable' through the headers are *undocumented* - most often indicated by a `detail::` namespace and/or `detail/` header folder(s).

---

Comment: "The return-value is specifically undocumented,"  How awful.  In my work, an issue would be raised against this and assigned to some poor intern.

Comment: I will have to add a wrapper around this, returning true if and only if the output size is greater than zero.

Comment: FYI I have committed code that checks for the intersection of line segments using boost::geometry.  This is half a dozen lines that wraps up the boost weirdness, replacing a great deal of tricky code I wrote to handle all the special cases in this problem.  It seems worthwhile to use boost for this, but I think I'll stick to my own code for straightforward geometry problems.  I do thank you for your advice on this over the last few days.

Comment: This is how the majority of boost libraries are intended to be used: they [aim for genericity](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html) above friendliness: they want to have value first, convenience "later". The whole point is that you **can** use their library with your own types, and of course you're supposed to hide the complexity - although how much can be a matter of perf/convenience trade-off

Comment: By the way: if you **do** want the boolean return code only, just use [`intersects`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects/intersects_2_two_geometries.html) of course. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94995b94b20d1c63

Comment: Why would anyone think it useful to provide one only?  Both the boolean AND the intersect point are needed.

Comment: Gee. Am I on trial? It's a standard. It's not even something that Boost Geometry (formerly GSL) came up with. They followed the OGC spec. It's pretty well-established. I'm not comfortable taking the "lazy rant" attitude with stuff that I cannot judge. I'm assuming there are pretty decent reasons. If you dive a little into said standard you will probably figure out the secret key. Or you can ask on the library mailing list?

Comment: Oh, maybe a slight reverse rant: in the functional/mathematical sense you **already have** both in perfect typing: "no intersection" is mathematically actually the "empty intersection" anyways. Why portray the same information redundantly? The interface is perfect. (The predicate version likely exists as an optimization because it can be implemented with smarts generic "relation" matrix coefficients - disclaimer I'm just rambling about some specification details I've seen once)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't think I was ranting.  Can two short sentences constitute a rant?  What I was hoping to do was provide insight into the problems encountered by an actual real library user who is trying to get something accomplished in the real world using your library.

Comment: In fairness, the entire question seemed a bit of a rant :) Three exclamation points are frequently a good symptom of that. No harm. I don't mind matching the level, while playing a bit of devil's advocate.

Comment: Oh, and :blush: it's not my library. I'm just a hermit who lives on StackOverflow - learning boost for fun and profit!

Comment: Actually I have stubbed my toes/banged my head against those walls so hard, so long, so often that I got a better sense of when it was poor library design (looking at you, Boost Process)  or excellent focus on value (Boost GIL, you horrible mistress, you are _good_ on the inside!)

Comment: It may not be your library, but you seem to be the only person around who has any idea how to make it work.

Comment: @ravenspoint I think you mean that as a compliment, but somehow it doesn't feel right. Anyhoops: [the other top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost-geometry/topusers) are all way more well-versed (and some actually library devs). I'm just more active on SO. Oh and did I mention their [mailing-list](https://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/geometry)?